# How can i set action bar color with transition?

Tags: android

I know how to set action bar color but i don't know how to do this with transition.
This is an example in css.

https://codepen.io/impressivewebs/embed/zohgt?height=220&type=result&href=zohgt&user=impressivewebs&safe=true&slug-hash=zohgt&default-tab=result&animations=run#result-box

How can i do it in android to set action bar color with transition?

I'm using AppCompat and i'm changing color of actionbar with this code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

And it's working. But i want to set it with transition. Can i do it?

Comment: there're two options. 1) value animator (as suggested by @sihrc answer) or 2) build a custom drawable yourself that will animate color transitions. 1) is easier, 2) is more universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) with a argb evaluator. In the on animation update, you can get your actionbar and set the color to the current value of the animator.